# Artifactory backup failing during export

Tags: backup, postgresql

We are using Jfrog artifactory version 6.7.0.
For backing up artifactory repositories we are following JFrog Artifactory documented backup policy - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Backups.

The artifactory binaries are installed in AWS EC2 instance and for DB we are using AWS RDS Postgresql engine. The connectivity and backups were working fine and no config changes were made but it stopped working for last 2 days.

Below are the log snippets from /data/artifactory/artifactory-pro-6.7.0/logs/artifactory.log ->

```
2019-04-30 00:00:00,000 [art-exec-16] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:624) - Beginning full system export...
2019-04-30 00:00:00,001 [art-exec-16] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:651) - Creating temp export directory: /data/artifactory/artifactory-pro-

6.7.0/backup/new_backup1/20190430.000000.tmp
2019-04-30 00:00:00,001 [art-exec-16] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:658) - Using backup directory: '/data/artifactory/artifactory-pro-

6.7.0/backup/new_backup1/20190430.000000.tmp'.
2019-04-30 00:00:00,001 [art-exec-16] [INFO ] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:566) - Exporting config...
2019-04-30 00:00:01,070 [art-exec-10] [INFO ] (o.a.r.s.t.p.TrashcanPruner:111) - Trashcan pruning total execution time: '1.07 secs'
2019-04-30 00:00:01,636 [art-exec-10] [INFO ] (o.a.s.b.s.GarbageCollectorInfo:80) - Storage garbage collector report:
Number of binaries:      170,933
Total execution time:    505 millis
Candidates for deletion: 0
Checksums deleted:       0
Binaries deleted:        0
Total size freed:        0 bytes
Current total size:      113.97 GB
2019-04-30 00:00:56,091 [art-exec-16] [ERROR] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:756) - Failed to check for config 'keystore' existence: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to check for config 'keystore' existence: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.ConfigsServiceImpl.hasConfig(ConfigsServiceImpl.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor401.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.hasConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.addon.webstart.keystore.DbKeyStoreService.keyStoreExists(DbKeyStoreService.java:129)
        at org.artifactory.addon.webstart.keystore.DbKeyStoreService.exportTo(DbKeyStoreService.java:346)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.exportTo(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.addon.webstart.WebstartAddonImpl.exportKeyStore(WebstartAddonImpl.java:64)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.exportTo(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:676)
        at org.artifactory.backup.BackupServiceImpl.backupSystem(BackupServiceImpl.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210.backupSystem(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.backup.BackupJob.runBackup(BackupJob.java:123)
        at org.artifactory.backup.BackupJob.runAutomaticBackup(BackupJob.java:91)
        at org.artifactory.backup.BackupJob.onExecute(BackupJob.java:68)
        at org.artifactory.schedule.quartz.QuartzCommand.execute(QuartzCommand.java:48)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor770.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2254)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor219.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:711)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:645)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:187)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.jfrog.storage.JdbcHelper.getConnection(JdbcHelper.java:123)
        at org.jfrog.storage.JdbcHelper.executeSelect(JdbcHelper.java:159)
        at org.jfrog.storage.JdbcHelper.executeSelect(JdbcHelper.java:139)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.dao.ConfigsDao.hasConfig(ConfigsDao.java:64)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.ConfigsServiceImpl.hasConfig(ConfigsServiceImpl.java:83)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mydb.aws.pnh.cloud: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
        ... 57 common frames omitted
2019-04-30 00:00:56,092 [art-exec-16] [ERROR] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:757) - Full system export failed: Failed to check for config 'keystore' existence: Communications link 

failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.: Failed to check for config 'keystore' existence: 

Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2019-04-30 00:00:56,092 [art-exec-16] [WARN ] (o.a.b.BackupJob     :95) - Backup completed with some errors (see the log messages above for details). Old backups will not be auto-removed.
2019-04-30 00:12:00,001 [art-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.r.c.VirtualCacheCleanupServiceImpl:123) - Starting cleanup of virtual repositories
2019-04-30 00:12:00,009 [art-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.r.c.VirtualCacheCleanupServiceImpl:127) - Completed virtual repositories cleanup: removed 0 cached files.
```

It will be really helpful if someone can point out the issue and provide a workaround .

Many Thanks,
Bluesaturn

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a DNS problem. Host `mydb.aws.pnh.cloud` could not be resolved.

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mydb.aws.pnh.cloud: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
```